# Emacs org export shell script from txt file

Tags: org-mode, org-export, batch-mode

I have a `.txt` file which is an org file but not with the `.org` file extension.

I want to export the file to html on the command line, but it does not work if the file extension is `.txt`, only if the file extension is `.org`.

```
$ emacs alspac_data_guide.txt --batch -f org-html-export-to-html --kill

Symbol’s function definition is void: org-html-export-to-html
```

I think this might be because it is not loading in org-mode? How do I modify the shell command to work correctly?

Comment: `--batch` implies `-q` so it does not load your init file: you have to load it (or, better, a small subset of it) with `-l`. All you should nee is to set the `load-path` and `(require 'org)`.

Answer (score 0):

Type `-*- mode:org -*-` at the top of file